Can a positive charge have a negative potential?
I'm studying about electrostatic potential due to a point charge and was wondering - can a positively charged point have negative electrostatic potential?
V=Kq/r for a positive point charge.

Assume B is the closest distance of approach for any test charge without experiencing a force due to the positive point charge. Now, if I want to move the point charge further towards point A, wouldn't I be performing negative work, and hence the point would have negative potential?
Our teacher also made us plot a graph, which obviously states otherwise. It suggests that no matter what the value of 'r' is, 'V' always remains positive.

Please help me understand this concept.

First, you need to understand that electrostatic potential (or, indeed, any type of potential energy) is an attribute of a system or configuration of charges - you cannot ascribe it to any individual charge. So although we may loosely speak of the potential of a test charge or the potential of a point in space, what we always mean is the potential of a specific arrangement of the main charge and a test charge.
Secondly, potential is not an absolute value - we can only ever speak of the relative potential of two different configurations. If we have to do work on the system to move from configuration A to configuration B then we say that configuration B has higher potential energy than configuration A. So if we (arbitrarily) call the potential of A zero, then configuration B has a positive potential. But we could equally well call the potential of B zero, in which case configuration A has a negative potential.
There is an often unstated convention that we take the zero point of potential energy as being the configuration where the main charge and the test charge have infinite separation (we sometime loosely say that "the potential at infinity" is zero). So the graph that your teacher has drawn shows how the potential energy of a positive test charge varies with its distance from a positive main charge using this convention. But if we set the zero point of potential energy to, say, the configuration where the test charge is one metre from the main charge, then a configuration where the test charge was further away than one metre would have a negative potential even though the test charge and the main charge are positive.

First: The concept of your point B does not make sense to me, the static coulomb field of the charge does not stop at some point, it will just get weaker the further away you are.
Secondly: Arguing with work and direction is a bit tricky semantically, but I would describe the situation as follows: When you push a positive test charge toward rising positive potential you do have to apply a force, that is directed into the direction of the movement of the particle compensating the repulsing coulomb force, so you are applying positive work to push the particle up the potential.
The potential on the other hand is applying a force against the direction of movement of the particle. So one could say the potential is doing negative work, meaning that it is converting the particles kinetic energy into positive potential energy.
Now to your actual question: The only physical action a potential will ever cause is applying a force proportional to its spacial derivative. In your case $\vec{F}_{coulomb} = q\cdot\vec{\nabla}\varphi(r)$ or in 1D $\vec{F}_{coulomb} = q\cdot\frac{\partial\varphi(x)}{\partial x}$, where $\varphi(r)$ is the electrostatic potential. This means any form of potential, that produces the same forces, will be valid for the description of your system. For example in the 1_D electro-static case you can add a spacial-constant to your potential: $\vec{F}_{coulomb} = q\cdot\frac{\partial\varphi(x)}{\partial x} = q\cdot\frac{\partial\varphi(x)}{\partial x}+ q\cdot\frac{\partial c}{\partial x}$ because $\frac{\partial c}{\partial x} = 0$. So you can always shift your potential up or down by a constant and the zero point of your potential is physically meaningless. Thus: yes, coulomb potential of a single charge could be choosen in a way, that it is negative through most of space and still describe the correct physical behavior.
Remark1 A generalization of this will lead to the gauge symmetry of electrodynamics allowing to change electric and magnetic potentials in a less trivial way that leaves the fields unchanged.
Remark2 In Quantum mechanics it is not strictly true that the only physical action caused by the potential is due to its derivative. See Aharonov–Bohm-effect for more details.

@Mel If one is to be perfectly correct, one must remember that potentials never do work; rather only forces arising from the potentials have any ability to do work. The work can, however, be related to a specific potential difference.

@AlbertusMagnus That helps me visualise it better, thanks for the input

The work done by an external force in moving unit positive test charge is the change in potential.
The test charge has two equal magnitude, opposite direction forces acting in it as shown in the diagram below.

To move the test charge closer to charge $+Q$ positive work has to be done by the external force which corresponds to an increase in the potential.
The formula $V=KQ/r$ was derived on the arbitrary but commonly accepted assumption that the potential at infinity is zero.
However you could if you so wished, although I do not know why you would do that, choose the zero of potential at some distance R from charge $+Q$.

Thus when r>R the potential will be negative but there will also be positions where the potential is positive.

I shall give an explicit example where a positive point charge interacts with a test charge so that the potential of that test charge is negative for any $r\gt 0$.
For example, as is noted in many of the earlier posts, the potential of a test charge in the presence of a positive point source is not an absolute quantity but rather depends on a point of reference. Now suppose we choose the reference so that the potential is zero at $r=\infty$. So a test charge $q$, at any finite distance $r$ from the source has a potential:
$$\Delta \varphi(\vec r)=-W/q=-\int_{\infty}^rd\varphi(\vec r)=-\varphi(\vec r).$$ Where the above result arises as a consequence of conservation of energy $\Delta E=0$, and the work energy theorem.

B will always be at infinity as per the convention we take. But if you want to change it for some reason, then it is possible that potential becomes negative once you go further away.
Logically, you can understand like this : When a charge is at infinity, force on it is taken to be zero. Now when you bring a test charge which is positive by convention, the positive charge will repel test charge and thus you are doing some work against the electric field so it is a non spontaneous process. Instead if you place negative charge the charge tends to go closer so you don't need to do work rather it itself tends to go towards it. This makes the work done negative and potential also negative as work done is stored in form of potential energy and potential is for unit charge. But for positive charge, you do against its will. You are increasing the potential energy of system and thus doing work leading to increase in potential for a unit charge. Hope it helps!

I get how my notion of point B is pretty much incorrect, but for a moment again, considering it's not at infinity, the graph I've attached in the question will no longer be valid, right? I suppose it's the generalised form for a spontaneous process only.

yes once you go further from the charge and cross that point moving towards infinity (not at infinity though), then with reference to that point, since it's not at infinity, the potential will be negative. So graph won't be valid. But by convention, we always consider infinity as reference point. even for an atom, if an electron is outside atom, it is considered infinity and it's energy there is considered zero though it always decreases as it comes closer to the atom. Thus, as science students, this will be how we will interpret potential.

Conventions are important since they set standards. Otherwise it would be upto a person what he/she wants to take as reference.

Alright, I get it now. Thanks for the input.
